# Как плавно изменить градиент фона при клике по элементу? (код внутри)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть два элемента, при клике по первому должен плавно измениться градиент у фона второго.
Вроде бы все нормально, но `transition` не срабатывает именно на фон, а к примеру, к прозрачности применяется.

```js
$('.one').click(function() {
  $('.two').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.two {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(#8BC34A 0%, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0) 70%);
  transition: background 1s;
}
.two.active {
    background: radial-gradient(#FF5722 0%, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0) 70%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="one" value="Жми">
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: Градиенты относятся к `background-image` который не анимируемый.
[Тут](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483364/css3-background-image-transition) есть несколько путей обхода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('.one').click(function() {
  $('.two').toggleClass('active');
})
```

```css
.two {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(#8BC34A 0%, rgba(21, 21, 21, 0) 70%);
}
.two:before {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
    background: radial-gradient(#FF5722 0%, #FFF 70%);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s;
}
.two.active:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="one" value="Жми">
<div class="two"></div>
```

Comment: да я так и думал решить, но это мне столько ненужных элементов добавит...